# ¿Como hago funcionar este sticky footer?

Tags: html5, css

Estoy intentando crear un sticky footer pero por algún motivo me tira hacia abajo el footer haciendo que no se vea hasta bajar la barra de navegación. Intente cambiar algunos margin pero no parece que ese sea el problema

```css
* {
  margin: 0; }

html {
  height: 100%; }

body {
  height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -40px; }
  .wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 40px; }

.site-footer {
  height: 40px; }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background: #333;
  margin: 0; }

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

h1 {
  font: 100% Impact, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 99px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }

footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: white; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Sumario de proyectos</h1>
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
    2017 &COPY; Nestor y Diego
</footer>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pero si es un footer siempre se ira hacia abajo, ¿Donde quieres que se vea?

Comment: @DiegoSanchezStrange Puedes colocar como correcta la respuesta que te halla dado una solución, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Remplaza la clase h1 por esta:

```
h1 {
  font: 100% Impact, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 99px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px; }
```

y a la clase site-footer agrégale:

```
.site-footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: @DiegoSanchezStrange si crees que esta respuesta fue suficiente para solucionar tu problema, marca como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0; }

html {
  height: 100%; }

body {
  height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -40px; }
  .wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 40px; }

  .site-footer {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
      right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background: #333;
  margin: 0; }

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

h1 {
font: 100% Impact, sans-serif;
color: white;
font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px; }

footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: white; }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Sumario de proyectos</h1>
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
    2017 &COPY; Nestor y Diego
</footer>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo funciona correctamente pero tu respuesta sería mucho mejor si explicaras que has hecho y porqué, no solo poner el código sin más. Puedes leer aquí [cómo elaborar una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)